# Access object required

Tags: ms-access, vba, runtime-error, ms-access-2010

I tried to use VBA in access 2010 to create login form, but I experienced an error message :

> run time error (424) object required.

Can anyone help me?

the code is:

```vb
Dim dbs As Database
Dim rstUserPwd As Recordset
Dim bFoundMatch As Boolean

Set dbs = CurrentDb
Set rstUserPwd = dbs.OpenRecordset("users")

bFoundMatch = False

If rstUserPwd.RecordCount > 0 Then
    rstUserPwd.MoveFirst

    ' check for matching records
    Do While rstUserPwd.EOF = True
        ' ERROR occurs on next line ...
        If rstUserPwd![user_name] = login.txtName.Value And rstUserPwd![Password] = login.txtPass.Value Then
            bFoundMatch = True
            Exit Do
        End If
        rstUserPwd.MoveNext
    Loop
End If

If bFoundMatch = True Then
    'Open the next form here and close this one
    DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.Name
    DoCmd.OpenForm "frmNavigation"
Else
    '
    MsgBox "Incorrect Username or Password"
End If

rstUserPwd.Close
```

Comment: What is `login.txtName`?

Comment: Like the comment below says, it would be of great help to know the breakpoint, but here are two guesses. First, login.txtname should probably have a form!  in front of it. you could also use me.txtnames.  Second, you may need to specify ado.database and ado.recordset in your first two lines.

Comment: login is the name of the form and the txtName is the name of the text field for entering the user name

Comment: Put a try catch around the code where the error seems to happen. Put a break point inside your catch, and it will bring you to the line that causes the error. Depending on how the architecture is done, you may have to repeat the process several times untill you get to the specific line causing the error. Once you find exactly on what line it happens, you will be able to solve your issue or to improve your chances to obtain a good answer that will help you by asking a better question...

Answer (score 0):

Where is it breaking?
Without knowing that, the first thing I'd do is add "dim dbs as database". For some reason it may not be seeing this implicitly. Check under Tools, references and make sure your DAO library is checked.

Edited to add -

After reading your reply regarding where the code is breaking, I believe your login form is corrupt. Try these recovery methods - http://www.datawright.com.au/access_resources/recovering_corrupted_form_or_report.htm

Comment: i'd did that. but the problem still exist

Comment: in the following line:
            If rstUserPwd![user_name] = login.txtName.Value And rstUserPwd![Password] = login.txtPass.Value Then 

I rtried to changer login.txtName to any string value such as "some text" like:  If rstUserPwd![user_name] = "some text". the problem has not appeared. but I still did not find the reason of the problem. can anyone help me?